# Angular Slice Pipe: Display New Line or Any Delimiting Character

Tags: angular, typescript, angular10

How do I get Angular Slice Pipe to display New Line or any delimited separator instead of commas, when separating an array?  Is there an option to choose? NewLine, / ,   ;  etc

```
addressOwnerArray = ['Michelle','Joe','Alex'];

"addressOwnerArray | slice : 0"
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?  The slice pipe itself doesn't introduce any delimiters, it simply returns a portion of an array.  Maybe you need to use `*ngFor`?  ex: `<li *ngFor="let name of addressOwnerArray | slice:0>{{ name }}</li>`. Or are you looking to combine array elements into a string, like using [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[slice pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe) extract somes elements from an array from start to end, If you want, you can use join in some like

```
<div [innerHtml]="addressOwnerArray.join('<br/>')"></div>
```

or a simple *ngFor to iterate over the array

```
<div *ngFor="let address of addressOwnerArray">{{address}}</div>

//or 
<span *ngFor="let address of addressOwnerArray">{{address}}<br/></span>

//or
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let address of addressOwnerArray">
     {{address}}
  </li>
</ul>
```